# First time that X has happened

Tags: python, pandas

this is a difficult one and rather a design question. I'm not looking for code, just for an idea on how to do the following in pandas. I'm first showing the data, then the question

Data:

```
             category          
year   group                                                                           
1983     722     1001
1983     722     1003  
1984     722     1001  
1984     721     1002
```

I have a data set that contains group-year observations. Typically, every group has for every year some units. These units have categories. I want to create an indicator at the group-year level that shows when a unit with that category was created *the first time*.

I figure that a better expected output would be a database as

```
year   group  newCategory                                                                    
1983     722         1001
1984     722         1003
1984     721         1002
```

**Update: Now that I did it, I added my approach as an answer**

Comment: Dictionary? Use the `category` as the key. If the key does not yet exist, add that `year` as the value. If it does exist, don't change it. Just a thought.

Comment: why do you want to have each category be a column? why wouldn't you just add a separate column that contains a marker when a new category is encountered for the first time?

Comment: Acushner: It can be more than one category. And I need to know which category it is. So I need to know 1980, group 1: New categories 1,2,5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the afterworld, here is what I ended up doing. I decided against the dictionary approach because I couldn't figure how to do that without iterating through rows, which would be quite inefficient.

```
def computeIndicators(group):
    # group is year-group 
    return pd.DataFrame(sub['category'].unique(), columns={'category'})

def computeInitialIndicators(group):
    # group is group-category 
    return group['year'].min()

results = patents.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(computeIndicators)
results = results.reset_index().drop('level_2', 1).sort(['group', 'year'])
results2 = results.groupby(['group', 'category']).apply(computeInitialIndicators)
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you use a new column like i mentioned in my comment, you could do something like this to get a marker each time a new category appeared for the first time.

```
s = set()
df['newcat'] = df.category.apply(lambda c: 0 if (c in s or s.add(c)) else 1)
```

Comment: Acushner: It can be more than one category. And I need to know which category it is. So I need to know 1980, group 1: New categories 1,2,5. A marker that only contains information *whether* at least one new category was hit is not sufficient.

Comment: yes, and the information of which specific category is new is available in the category column.

Comment: But there are more than one unit per year, hence (potentially) more than one category per year. How do I know which one(s) is (are) the new one?